# Owncloud 8 and OpenLDAP disable useMemberOfToDetectMembership

Tags: raspbian, owncloud, openldap

I have set up a OpenLDAP server and OwnCloud 8 on raspbian.
LDAP itself and OwnCloud are working, but when I try to login to OwnCloud via LDAP I get the following errors:

```
Array to string conversion at /mnt/8gb/www/owncloud/lib/private/template/functions.php#36
ldap_read(): Search: Invalid DN syntax at /mnt/8gb/www/owncloud/apps/user_ldap/lib/ldap.php#257
```

I read in several forums that I have to set useMemberOfToDetectMembership to 0 (basically disable it) to make it work.

But unfortunate I have no idea how to do it, because all the tutorials I found are based on a centOs command line...

Can somebody help me how I can achieve this under raspbian?

Comment: Based on what CentOS command line? It's an OwnCloud setting, not an OpenLDAP setting. The alternative is surely to enable the `memberOf` overlay in OpenLDAP.

Answer (score 0):

On the commandline, `cd` to your OwnCloud install directory. You will find a script called `occ` there. This is the OwnCloud command-line client.

Check your LDAP settings first (you may have to run this as the user that owns the OwnCloud directories):

`php5 occ ldap:show-config`

This prints a table, the header usually says `| Configuration | s01 |` (referring to the 1st LDAP server), but instead of `s01` you may have an empty string or `s02`. Let's assume it is `s01`. Check what the `useMemberOfToDetectMembership` setting says. To set it to 0:

`php5 occ ldap:set-config "s01" useMemberOfToDetectMembership 0`

Remember to use whatever is appropriate instead of `"s01"` above.

PS. I used this with OwnCloud 8.2 but it is very likely to work with other versions, too.